# A metric space on the rationals would mean every element was an isolated point?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Would this be true? Every element of the metric space on the rationals with the standard metric would mean that every point was an isolated point. Would this be a metric space?

Comment: Can you try to restate your question as a single clear sentence?

Comment: Would a metric space on the rationals be a space of only isolated points?

Comment: Im not sure if isolated can only be used to refer to sets in metric spaces or spaces themselves.

Comment: $\mathbb Q$ with the induced metric as a metric subspace of $\mathbb R$, does not consist of isolated points, every open ball around any point has infinitely many rationals. There are other metrics that make $\mathbb Q$ consist of isolated points .

Comment: PS I don't understand what it means to say a space or a set is isolated. A set/space that consists only of isolated points is said to be discrete.

Answer (score 1):

Every point of $\mathbb{Q}$ with the standard metric $d$ will *not* be isolated. If $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ were an isolated point, we could find an open ball (relative to the topology on $\mathbb{Q}$) $B(x,\epsilon)$ not containing any other points in $\mathbb{Q}$. Now, $B(x,\epsilon)$ is precisely the set
$$
B(x,\epsilon) = \left\{ r \in \mathbb{Q} : |x-r| < \epsilon \right\}.
$$
However, it is well known that one can always find a rational number $r \neq x$ with $|x-r| < \epsilon$. Hence, every neighbourhood of $x$ (relative to the metric structure of $\mathbb{Q}$) will contain a rational number different than $x$.

It is true that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a metric space (and a metric subspace of $\mathbb{R}$) when equipped with the metric $d(x,y) := |x-y|$. More generally, let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $Y$ a subset of $X$. If $d_Y$ denotes the restriction of $d$ to $Y \times Y$, then the pair $(Y,d_Y)$ will itself be a metric space.

Now, say we give $\mathbb{Q}$ the  discrete metric 
$$
d(x,y) := \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if } x \neq y,\\
0 & \text{if }x  =y.
\end{cases}
$$
(I will leave it to you to verify that $d$ is indeed a metric on $\mathbb{Q}$). With this metric, $\mathbb{Q}$ will consist *only* of isolated points. Indeed, for each $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, the open ball $B(x,1)$ will contain *only* the point $x$.